# What is youtube policy for video-id?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am crawling youtube videos using following url:

**URL** : https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category="category_term"

I parse above obtained response to get the video Id's.
  Now I want to know whether youtube reuses Video-id if the video is removed from youtube 
  server?

Why I am asking this is because I need to query youtube server for every video ID to know
  if the video exist or not.

Please let me know about Video-id policy of youtube. This will help me to avoid extra
  request to youtube server just to know about video existence.

Answer (score 0):

videos are never removed from YouTube servers and video urls are never reused

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me describe a scenario where a user upload a video to youtube, after that the same video I got from youtube api. What if the user who uploaded it delete the video? Will youtube still persist it? And if it does so, will the video be available for viewing on my application? Thnx in advance.

Comment: once a video is "deleted", it's not accessible through the api or anywhere really. The video is still stored on YouTube's servers with the id associated with it. YouTube doesn't reuse youtube video urls because videos that were "deleted" can be restored. One time my channel was compromised and I had Partner support restore them. If they reused urls, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: So here we mean that youtube does not reuse the VidoId. So in that case, how I can come to know about deletion of such videos, because if a user views such video on my site, it will give an error, as the video is not available for streaming through api? In addition I don't want to request youtube to check for video existence. Thnx

Comment: Thank you. So you mean video-ids are not reused. In that case consider the scenario, for 1st crawl I get video say A from youtube and then this video is deleted whoever uploaded it. So next time I crawl yoytube won't give me video A as it is now deleted and give me another video say B. Now here how I cam come to know about existence of video A. Please comment on this. Thnx in advance

Comment: the person above doesn't know what they're talking about... I've personally had youtube restore "deleted" videos without having to get them information. Even things like privacy settings stayed. Think about it. Videos get deleted by youtube and restored all the time. I don't know much about YouTube's API but as a long time YouTuber I can assure you the video stay. Videos are "deleted" and IDs are never used on other videos.

Comment: on top of that, I have a friend who had his account disabled for terms of service and when the account was reopened, the videos that were "deleted" were back..

Answer (score 0):

Its not TRUE that video's are not removed from YouTube servers

Video's are removed and also Blocked

But yes **Video** Id's as well as **Playlist** id's , **channel** Id's **never changes**

If you want to check and also search for video's or playlist or what ever on YouTube you shall use
**[YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)** which provide a wide range of methods to list update, upload video's playlist etch

### [YouTube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

The YouTube Data API (v3) lets you incorporate YouTube functionality into your own application. You can use the API to fetch search results and to retrieve, insert, update, and delete resources like videos or playlists.

In conjunction with the YouTube Player APIs and the YouTube Analytics API, the API lets your application provide a full-fledged YouTube experience that includes search and discovery, content creation, video playback, account management, and viewer statistics.

for checking the existence of Video you can  use [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it)

for checking the existence of Playlist you can  use [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

Comment: Thank you. So you mean video-ids are not reused. In that case consider the scenario, for 1st crawl I get video say A from youtube and then this video is deleted whoever uploaded it. So next time I crawl yoytube won't give me video A as it is now deleted and give me another video say B. Now here how I cam come to know about existence of video A. Please comment on this. Thnx in advance

Comment: @user2245582 You can check the existence of video